# Fast way to clean up imported geometry?

Tags: subdivision-surface, retopology

Is there a fast way to clean up imported geometry so it works with subdivision surface modifier? If i use subdiv here those stretched triangles create weird artifacts. I know rebuilding would work, but was wondering if there is an easier / faster way.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Example:

After importing a file like an STL file try doing a **limited dissolve**.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Comment: Thanks, but if using Limited Dissolve and applying a Subdivison Surface Afterwards the Openings are not working anymore. So this is not the solution.